# checkbox in listView.separated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do checkboxes in the list view flutter but when I select one all are selected, I want to select only the one I click not all. also, How I can know which items are selected

here is my code:

```dart
 bool value = false;
ListView.separated(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
    height: 100,
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
    ),
    child: ListTile(
        title: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:
              MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment:
              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(list[index].name),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                  CheckboxListTile(
                        value: value,
                        onChanged:
                            (bool value) {
                          this.value = value;
                        },
                      )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    ),
  ),
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
      SizedBox(
    height: 5,
  ),
  itemCount: 5,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using single bool to select the list. That's why you are getting this behavior.  You can create an empty list to tract the selected items.

You can follow this example code

```dart
class ChWL extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChWL({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChWL> createState() => _ChWLState();
}

class _ChWLState extends State<ChWL> {
  List<int> list = List.generate(33, (index) => index);
  List<int> selectedItem = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text("${list[index]}"),
          value: selectedItem.contains(list[index]),
          onChanged: (value) {
            bool isChecked = selectedItem.contains(list[index]);

            if (isChecked) {
              selectedItem.remove(list[index]);
            } else {
              selectedItem.add(list[index]);
            }

            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and how I can get which item is clicked?

Comment: fo example if two item is ched how I can know them

Comment: because I want to do thing with the selected iitems

Comment: Try to test snippet ? From `selectedItem` will provide a list that is needed, else use model class.

Answer (score -1):

```dart
 Row(
              children: [
                Text(list[index].name),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                  CheckboxListTile(
                        value: value,
                        onChanged:
                            (bool value) {
```

Comment: Can you include more description

Comment: This seems to be a verbatim copy of (a fragment of) the code in the question. It cannot possibly answer it.